# Does allowing a std::fstream to be destroyed close the associated file?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if I need an RAII wrapper around `std::fstream`....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you don't. It closes the file. `§ 27.8.1.2`:

```
virtual ˜basic_filebuf();
```

> **Effects:** Destroys an object of class basic_filebuf. Calls close().

(which is contained as an object within `std::fstream` (`§ 27.8.1.11`), thus being destructed when the `fstream` is destructed).